Definition of equilibrium of a system of particles
I am reading Goldstein's book on Classical Mechanics. There in the first chapter , under the topic of D'Alembert's Principle , I have some confusion. He says that

Suppose there is a system of N particles in equilibrium. Then the total force on each particle must vanish i.e. $\vec {F_i} =0$. Then clearly the virtual work on each of the particles also vanishes and thus the total virtual work on the system is $0$.

Why should the force on each particle be zero ? Shouldn't the net force on the system be zero for equilibrium to exist while individual particles might experience a non-zero force ?

Perhaps by “a system of $n$ particles in equilibrium” the author means “a system, composed of $n$ particles that are all in equilibrium”?
